# How to disable badge on accounts icon on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

After installing the Gitlens extension, there will be a badge (showing digit 1) on accounts icon.
I do not want to sign in to use Gitlens. How can i make that badge disappear?

[image: badge on account icon]

Comment: A workaround is to hide the accounts icon entirely by right click the accounts icon and choose "Hide Accounts"

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same quandary and [ended up finding a solution here](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/discussions/1408). Look for the following setting and switch it to false:

```
"gitlens.integrations.enabled": false
```

I don't know what this all disables, as far as I can tell, just github integration.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.63 (Nov. 2021) should alleviate that issue: see [issue 136300](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136300) and [commit 2368392](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/2368392b9b3b2bb5ff430bc7ff42c03ab64e4854)

It won't show an account badge if you are not logged in. No need to "Hide Accounts".